# Next Greater Element segfault can't figure out

Tags: c++

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;


 // } Driver Code Ends
class Solution
{
    public:
    //Function to find the next greater element for each element of the array.
    vector<long long> nextLargerElement(vector<long long> arr, int n){
        // Your code here
        vector<long long> res;
        stack<long long> stk, resStack;
        for(int i=n-1; i>=0; i--){
            if(stk.empty()){ 
                resStack.push(-1);
                stk.push(arr[i]);
            }
            else{
                while(!stk.empty() && stk.top() <= arr[i]) stk.pop();
                resStack.push(stk.top());
                stk.push(arr[i]);
            }       
        }
        while(!resStack.empty()){
            res.push_back(resStack.top()), resStack.pop();
        }
        return res;
    }
};

// { Driver Code Starts.

int main()
{
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        
        int n;
        cin>>n;
        vector<long long> arr(n);
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            cin>>arr[i];
        
        Solution obj;
        vector <long long> res = obj.nextLargerElement(arr, n);
        for (long long i : res) cout << i << " ";
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}  // } Driver Code Ends
```

Given an array arr[ ] of size N having distinct elements, the task is to find the next greater element for each element of the array in order of their appearance in the array.
Next greater element of an element in the array is the nearest element on the right which is greater than the current element.
If there does not exist next greater of current element, then next greater element for current element is -1. For example, next greater of the last element is always -1.

Comment: please suggest which part of code is giving error and how could i resolve that.

Comment: Did you try running your code through a debugger? Also please for the love of god don't use ``#include<bits/stdc++.h>; using namespace std;`` it is just **awful** practice and for whatever minute time saving benefits you get, you are risking a lot.

Comment: Please include all relevant info to reproduce the problem, a.k.a. a [mcve]. Also, you can [edit] your question, no need to put relevant info into the comments here. Also, in case you haven't, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: What is your data for which you have an error. We cannot try every possible vector size and data...

Comment: Your code can execute `resStack.push(stk.top());` when the stack is empty which is **undefined behavior**.